AttributeError: 'Conv2D' object has no attribute 'output_shape' for visualising CNN
I'm trying to use Keras (visualkeras) lib for visualizing my CNN model but I keep getting the errors.
Here's the model:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, ReLU, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, Dense, AveragePooling2D, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
import visualkeras

def get_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(2, 2), padding='same', input_shape=(64, 64, 3), name='conv1'))
    model.add(ReLU(name='relu1'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name='pool1'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4, name='dropout1'))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(2, 2), padding='same', name='conv2'))
    model.add(ReLU(name='relu2'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name='pool2'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4, name='dropout2'))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(2, 2), padding='same', name='conv3'))
    model.add(ReLU(name='relu3'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name='pool3'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4, name='dropout3'))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(2, 2), padding='same', name='conv4'))
    model.add(ReLU(name='relu4'))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(2, 2), padding='same', name='conv5'))
    model.add(ReLU(name='relu5'))

    model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(8, 8), name='pool4'))
    model.add(Flatten(name='flatten'))

    model.add(Dense(1, name='fc'))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid', name='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

model = get_model()

visualkeras.layered_view(model, to_file='C:/m/visualkeras_output.png').show()

And this is the error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 47
     41 model = get_model()
     43 # Использование plot_model для визуализации модели
     44 #plot_model(model, to_file='C:/Users/j-puf/Documents/master/output.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
     45 
     46 # Использование visualkeras для визуализации модели
---> 47 visualkeras.layered_view(model, to_file='C:/Users/j-puf/Documents/master/visualkeras_output.png').show()

File c:\users\j-puf\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\visualkeras\layered.py:85, in layered_view(model, to_file, min_z, min_xy, max_z, max_xy, scale_z, scale_xy, type_ignore, index_ignore, color_map, one_dim_orientation, background_fill, draw_volume, padding, spacing, draw_funnel, shade_step, legend, font, font_color)
     82 y = min_xy
     83 z = min_z
---> 85 if isinstance(layer.output_shape, tuple):
     86     shape = layer.output_shape
     87 elif isinstance(layer.output_shape, list) and len(
     88         layer.output_shape) == 1:  # drop dimension for non seq. models

AttributeError: 'Conv2D' object has no attribute 'output_shape'


The lib is updated and I don't know the reason for the error. Maybe there's some other types of the same way visualization

There is an open issue on the GitHub for visualkeras here https://github.com/paulgavrikov/visualkeras/issues/51.  The Pull Request for the fix appears to be stalled, but the code change can be seen, and you could modify your local copy to match it. See lines 85-96 here

@nigh_anxiety maybe you also know if this lib could make some labels for each component of the structure?

Based on the documentation it looks like want to pass legend=True to layered_view()
